# How to re-order divs based on json value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a filtering function in my application. User can select how he wants to reorder the users based on wage or rating. I get the correct data with json but I am stuck how to re-order the elements.

Lets say I have a listing with

`<div class="col-md-12 profile_thumbnail_box" data-id="1"></div>`

and

```
<div class="col-md-12 profile_thumbnail_box" data-id="4"></div>
```

where `data-id` is the `user_id`. And right now there are two users.

Now when user changes the order (let's say wage- cheapest at the top) I get this json :

```
[  
    {  
        "user_id":4,
        "wage":"4",
        "lat":59.46,
        "lng":24.83,
        "recommended":"2",
        "rating":"1,5",
        "distance":5.2153552636895
    },
    {  
        "user_id":1,
        "wage":"6",
        "lat":59.44,
        "lng":24.74,
        "recommended":"1",
        "rating":"4,5",
        "distance":0.92971285651468
    }
]
```

Now the first `user_id` is 4. How can I reorder the divs where the `data-id=4` would be the first or if there are more users and data returned then how can I position them based on the returned `user_id` value?

EDIT:

Here is the jquery for changing the filters

```
  //when user changes the filters
  $('.order_listing').on('change', function() {
    // $(".loading-icon").show();
    var users = [];
    $(".profile_thumbnail_box").each(function() {
      var data_ids = $(this).attr("data-id");
      users.push(data_ids);
    });
    console.log(users);
    //data to send
    var filterData = {
      order_type: $(".order_listing").val(),
      lat: localStorage.getItem("latitude"),
      lng: localStorage.getItem("longitude"),
      user_ids : users
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/search/filters",
      data: filterData,
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);

        $(".loading-icon").hide();
      },
      error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown, data) {
        console.log(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown, data);

      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Depends how are you creating the elements, is this supposed to be ordered at creation, or after, or both? What have you attempted?

Comment: Show us the code creating the elements

Comment: @PatrickEvans elements are created on load and sorted based on distance at first. I would like to reorder the elements after user selects a drop down. Check edit for the change function.

Comment: you can reload the content of the parent div by using ajax. It's not possible that you will have only two records.

Comment: @PatrickEvans the initial elements are created in the back-end and the content is returned as json

Comment: What you could do is call jQuery's detach() function on all the elements,. And then re-attach them using appendTo()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can implement your own `sort()` logic which re-orders the `.profile_thumbnail_box` elements based on the position of the object which matched their `data_id` in the array you retrieve from the AJAX request, something like this:

```js
// in your AJAX success handler...
var data = [{
  "user_id": 4,
  "wage": "4",
  "lat": 59.46,
  "lng": 24.83,
  "recommended": "2",
  "rating": "1,5",
  "distance": 5.2153552636895
}, {
  "user_id": 1,
  "wage": "6",
  "lat": 59.44,
  "lng": 24.74,
  "recommended": "1",
  "rating": "4,5",
  "distance": 0.92971285651468
}, {
  "user_id": 3
  // ...
}, {
  "user_id": 2
  // ...
}]
var ids = data.map(function(e) { return e.user_id; });

$('.profile_thumbnail_box').sort(function(a, b) {
  var aId = $(a).data('id'),
    bId = $(b).data('id');
  return (ids.indexOf(aId) || 0) > (ids.indexOf(bId) || 0);
}).appendTo('#container');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 profile_thumbnail_box" data-id="1">user #1</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 profile_thumbnail_box" data-id="2">user #2</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 profile_thumbnail_box" data-id="3">user #3</div>
  <div class="col-md-12 profile_thumbnail_box" data-id="4">user #4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if there are more users than just two?

Comment: This code will work for any number of users. The important part is that the `data-id` in the HTML matches with the `user_id` of an object in the returned array

Comment: I updated the answer to show you it working with more users in an arbitrary order.

Comment: omg you are the legend. I have been struggling this for hours. Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over the items in the JSON object, find the corresponding DOM element and append it to its container.

```
function reorder(users) {
    users.forEach(function(user) {
        var element = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${user['user_id']}"]`);
        if (element === null) {
            return;
        }
        element.parentElement.appendChild(element);
    });
}
```

You would then call the `reorder` method with the new JSON you've retrieved from the server.

Because an element can only appear once in the DOM, it will be taken out of its original position and placed back at the bottom of the element it is appended to. When you process all elements this way they will appear in the desired order.